# How would I construct the phrase "brief set of appendices"?

Tags: word-choice, latin

I'm writing fiction and currently working on appendices for my novel (or possibly alternatively for my website). I'd like to indicate that these are not 'complete' appendices but are sort of a work-in-progress. For example, the glossary for my world will continue to grow.

Basically, I don't mind generating canon for my world, because it already exists in my mind, and I don't mind 'putting it out there,' but then... I prefer to be conservative in this pursuit so that I don't constrain myself too much when writing future novels in the world. So at the moment, my appendices read more like author notes.

If I preface the appendices with:

*Appendices brevia*

Does that communicate that these are incomplete and/or in-progress? Is the construction correct from an English language perspective? Is there a better set of words that I could use to communicate my intent here?

**^^That's the question,** but it might not be pointed enough and I hope it's on topic.

Maybe I should call them *Author's World-building Notes* and leave it at that. Save the esteemed label of "Appendix" for when the notes reach Tolkienesque status. Your input is welcome.

Comment: In what languages does *brevia* mean *work-in-progress*? Not English. [Not Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brevis).  (And shouldn't it be *appendices breves* if it were Latin anyway, since *appendix* is feminine?)  And because *brief* is cognate to *brevis* in Latin, people would understand *appendices breves* to mean *short appendixes*, which is what it probably actually means in Latin.

Comment: @PeterShor I was aiming for 'abbreviated,' as in 'incomplete.' To convey the idea of 'there's more than this.' (would 'breves' convey this?)  I also figured Latin was fair game here... Hopefully it is... And the gender consistency between words is exactly the sort of thing I wondered about. Along those lines I wondered if there is a similar word in Latin indicating 'work in progress' and what the strengths and weaknesses of either would be.

Comment: Even an incomplete appendix is still an appendix. In fact, a single entry would still be an appendix (of some kind). I see no reason why the word itself can't be used, despite the perceived quality of its content. I know of no publisher that would add an adjective to any of the front-matter or back-matter terms. And the terms that *are* used are fairly standard.

Comment: @DPT: when does "short" mean "incomplete"? When does "abbreviated" mean "work in progress"? I don't think it does. Not in English, and I would assume not in Latin, either. And if you don't know Latin, why are you trying to come up with Latin phrases on your own? Furthermore, this isn't right the place to ask for Latin phrases, either; this site is about English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems to be really about Latin and not English.

Comment: Doesn't need to be about Latin. Appendix is an English word with Latin roots. I'm as happy calling the appendices "Appendices in brief" as "Appendices breves"--which is the sort of feedback I am seeking. How would one construct a phrase to suggest that a set of appendices may be longer at some future point? @JasonBassford indicates that it is a nonsensical question as anything appended is an appendix, but when my critique partners read my appendices they say "These aren't really appendices. They are too short."

Comment: You're a writer. Figure out what you want to say, and then figure out a way to say it. For example, *Appendix: A few remarks on world-building* would not only tell the reader what the appendix is about, but also indicate that there's much more that you could say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that

- *Appendices brevia* is not an English phrase.
- A printed book is fixed, not a "work in progress".
- A web page usually *is* a "work in progress", or dormant.

then your phrase

> *Author's World-building Notes*

seems to be the right approach.

Comment: A printed book is only a fixed thing in its current printed edition. As a manuscript submitted to editors for consideration for their press, or as a (second, third) edition of a published work, it begins to edge toward something less fixed.